# Sharepoint Approval Workflow Document Movement

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to create a sharepoint workflow that will automatically move a document from one folder to another when it is approved?

If possible, please share how it can be done.

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What value would be derived from moving the approved document to a folder? I ask because the built-in content approval settings may make an "approved" folder unnecessary, depending on the underlying requirements.